# Помогите решить проблему с обрпботкой кнопок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, inline

Пишу бота на python с библиотекой PyTelegramBotAPI и столкнулся с проблемой что при нажатии на первые кнопки все работает а вторые не обрабатывает, хотя ошибок программа не видит.

````
from typing import Text
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)



    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('CV', callback_data = 'CV')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Vacancy', callback_data= 'Vacancy')

    markup.add(item1)
    markup.add(item2)
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "What would you like to create:", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'CV':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Development (Frontend, backend, full-stack, mobile, web, gamedev)', callback_data = '1')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Testing', callback_data = '2')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DevOps/Admin', callback_data = 'DevOps/Admin')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Data Science', callback_data = 'Data Science')
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('TOP Management (CTO, CIO, Director)', callback_data = 'TOP Management')
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Support, Helpdesk', callback_data = 'Support, Helpdesk')
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PR, marketing, advertising. ', callback_data = 'PR')
            item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Project/Product manager,HR', callback_data = 'Project')
            item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Design', callback_data = 'Design')

            markup.add(item1)
            markup.add(item2,item3,item4)
            markup.add(item5)
            markup.add(item6,item8)
            markup.add(item7,item9)

            
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "CV - Choose a specialization :", reply_markup=markup)

        elif call.data == 'Vacancy':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)


            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('less then $1000', callback_data = 'less')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('$1000-$3000', callback_data = 'less')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('$3000-$6000', callback_data = 'less')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('more then $6000', callback_data = 'less')
  
            markup.add(item1)
            markup.add(item2)
            markup.add(item3)
            markup.add(item4)

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Your budget($):", reply_markup=markup)


#Блок ниже не обрабатывает кнопки


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call_1:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == '1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

            item_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Development (Frontend, backend, full-stack, mobile, web, gamedev)', callback_data = 'Development')
            
            markup.add(item_1)
           
            
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "CV - Choose a specialization :", reply_markup=markup)

        elif call.data == '2':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)


            item_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('less then $1000', callback_data = 'less')
            
            markup.add(item_1)
         

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Your budget($):", reply_markup=markup)






bot.polling(none_stop=True) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обработать два `callback_query_handler` так:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == '1 ваша кнопка')
def callback1(message):
   ... 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == '2 ваша кнопка')
def callback2(message):
   ...
```

Иначе первый 'хэндлер обработки кнопки' перекрывает вторую.

Comment: а что после def callback1,2(message): просто я только вчера начал писать код

Comment: @Vitaha Like ваш код, что вы и писали

Comment: @Vitaha Like если вас устроил ответ, пожалуйста, оцените его голосом.